# Get correspondence of screen line to TStrings line in TMemo descendant

Tags: delphi-10-seattle, tmemo

`TRichEdit` is causing too much access violations and issues in popup menu when styles are set, therefore I am trying to make a simple colorful `TMemo` descendant where each line from `Lines` could be painted with its own color as a whole.

I cannot influence the edit control from Windows, but can paint strings over it.

At first I tried to iterate through `Lines` property, but it caused problems with scrolling. So I decided to query strings from edit control directly using Win API.

For now everything is painted fine except colors: The lines requested from Windows edit control are the screen lines, not the lines from `Lines` property when `WordWrap := True;` and `ScrollBars := ssVertical;`.

How to find out the screen -> `Lines` line number correspondence?

```
unit ColoredEditMain;

interface

uses
  Winapi.Windows, Winapi.Messages, System.SysUtils, System.Variants, System.Classes, Vcl.Graphics,
  Vcl.Controls, Vcl.Forms, Vcl.Dialogs, Vcl.StdCtrls;

type
  TMyMemo = class(TMemo)
  private
    procedure WMPaint(var msg: TWMPaint); message WM_PAINT;
  end;

  TForm1 = class(TForm)
  private
    _memo: TMyMemo;
  public
    constructor Create(AOwner: TComponent); override;
  end;

var
  Form1: TForm1;

implementation

uses
  Vcl.Themes;

{$R *.dfm}

{ TMyMemo }

procedure TMyMemo.WMPaint(var msg: TWMPaint);
var
  Buffer: Pointer;
  PS: TPaintStruct;
  DC: HDC;
  i: Integer;
  X, Y: Integer;
  OldColor: LongInt;
  firstLineIdx: Integer;
  charsCopied, lineCount: Integer;
  lineLength: Word;
  bufLength: Integer;
begin
  try
  DC := msg.DC;
  if DC = 0 then
    DC := BeginPaint(Handle, PS);
  try
    X := 5;
    Y := 1;
    SetBkColor(DC, Color);
    SetBkMode(DC, Transparent);
    OldColor := Font.Color;
    firstLineIdx := SendMessage(Handle, EM_GETFIRSTVISIBLELINE, 0, 0);
    lineCount := SendMessage(Handle, EM_GETLINECOUNT, 0, 0);
    for i:=firstLineIdx to lineCount-1 do begin
      SelectObject(DC, Font.Handle);
      if odd(i) then
        SetTextColor(DC, clRed)
      else
        SetTextColor(DC, OldColor);
      lineLength := SendMessage(Handle, EM_LINELENGTH, WPARAM(i), 0);
      bufLength := lineLength*2 + 2;
      GetMem(Buffer, bufLength);
      try
        ZeroMemory(Buffer, bufLength);
        PWord(Buffer)^ := lineLength;
        charsCopied := SendMessage(Handle, EM_GETLINE, WPARAM(i), LPARAM(Buffer));
        //ShowMessage(IntToStr(lineLength) + ' ' + IntToStr(charsCopied) + '=' + Strpas(PWideChar(Buffer)));
        if Y > ClientHeight then Exit();
        TextOut(DC, X, Y, PWideChar(Buffer), lineLength);
      finally
        FreeMem(Buffer, bufLength);
      end;
      Inc(Y, Abs(Font.Height) + 2);
    end;
  finally
    if msg.DC = 0 then
      EndPaint(Handle, PS);
  end;
  except
    on ex: Exception do MessageBox(Handle, PWideChar('WMPaint: ' + ex.Message), nil, MB_ICONERROR);
  end;
end;

{ TForm1 }

constructor TForm1.Create(AOwner: TComponent);
var
  i, j: Integer;
  txt: string;
begin
  inherited;
  Left := 5;
  Top := 5;
  _memo := TMyMemo.Create(Self);
  _memo.Parent := Self;
  _memo.Align := alClient;
  _memo.WordWrap := True;
  _memo.ReadOnly := True;
  _memo.ScrollBars := ssVertical;

  for i := 0 to 10 do begin
    txt := '';
    for j := 0 to 100 do
      txt := txt + 'Line ' + IntToStr(i) + '.' + IntToStr(j) + ' ';
    _memo.Lines.Add(txt);
  end;
end;

end.
```

**Update**

I always thought that `TMemo` keeps original lines in its `Lines` collection, but in fact it spoils its `Lines` just after adding an item. When Word wrapping is on, adding a really long line converts it to several screen lines.

BUT! Surprisingly Windows `edit` control internally keeps the original lines as a whole on control resize.

Comment: You are better off finding a 3rd party Edit/Memo control that already supports what you need (there are many available), rather than paint it yourself and trying to figure out how the OS decides to split lines. At the very least, you should look at the VCL's source code to see how the `TMemo.Lines` property is implemented (hint, see the `TMemoStrings` class) and how it queries the Win32 API

Comment: PlusMemo and SynEdit are available via GetIt Package Manager, and allow colored text already. They're free with source. Why are you reinventing the wheel at all?